# pip install error every time: subprocess-exited-with-error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

If I try to install any module I am getting this kind of error every single time.

```
C:\Users\Aditya>pip install pandas
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -etuptools (c:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\site-packages)
Collecting pandas
  Using cached pandas-2.0.2.tar.gz (5.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [73 lines of output]
      Collecting setuptools>=61.0.0
        Using cached setuptools-67.8.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 MB)
      Collecting wheel
        Using cached wheel-0.40.0-py3-none-any.whl (64 kB)
      Collecting Cython<3,>=0.29.33
        Using cached Cython-0.29.35-py2.py3-none-any.whl (988 kB)
      Collecting oldest-supported-numpy>=2022.8.16
        Using cached oldest_supported_numpy-2022.11.19-py3-none-any.whl (4.9 kB)
      Collecting versioneer[toml]
        Using cached versioneer-0.28-py3-none-any.whl (45 kB)
      Collecting numpy==1.19.3 (from oldest-supported-numpy>=2022.8.16)
        Using cached numpy-1.19.3.zip (7.3 MB)
        Installing build dependencies: started
        Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
        Getting requirements to build wheel: started
        Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'error'
        error: subprocess-exited-with-error

        Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
        exit code: 1

        [40 lines of output]
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
            main()
          File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
            json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
          File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 112, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
            backend = _build_backend()
          File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 77, in _build_backend
            obj = import_module(mod_path)
          File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
            return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 972, in _find_and_load_unlocked
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
          File "C:\Users\Aditya\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-bpho9u3i\overlay\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 253, in <module>
            monkey.patch_all()
          File "C:\Users\Aditya\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-bpho9u3i\overlay\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\monkey.py", line 101, in patch_all
            patch_for_msvc_specialized_compiler()
          File "C:\Users\Aditya\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-bpho9u3i\overlay\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\monkey.py", line 164, in patch_for_msvc_specialized_compiler
            patch_func(*msvc9('find_vcvarsall'))
          File "C:\Users\Aditya\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-bpho9u3i\overlay\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\monkey.py", line 151, in patch_params
            mod = import_module(mod_name)
          File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
            return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
          File "C:\Users\Aditya\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-bpho9u3i\overlay\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 295, in <module>
            raise DistutilsPlatformError("VC %0.1f is not supported by this module" % VERSION)
        distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: VC 6.0 is not supported by this module
        [end of output]

        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      error: subprocess-exited-with-error

      Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
      exit code: 1

      See above for output.

      note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I tried many things, I tried pip upgrade, setup tools upgrade, wheels upgrade. I tried many other suggestions from CHATGPT and other Youtube channels. But nothing worked. I even uninstalled python and then reinstalled it again. But no use. This error is not only with pandas, but with every single module I try to install. Can anyone provide me a solution for this, it's very annoying to deal with.

Comment: You seem to have a weird msys Python install – get the official Python 3.11 from python.org and use it instead.